# Can I place a 4c cable inside existing cable channels alongside with power delivering ones?

Tags: phone-wiring

I bought 20 meters of 4c cable in order to replace existing phone ones (voice only). The reason why is that I want to place some new phone RJ11 plugs.

But I don't know if I can place inside the existing cable channels (where existing cables do reside) alongside the existing power cables as well.

The alternate approach is to place it externally, but it is ugly looking.

So should, is it recommended, to place it alongside the electric cables or not?

Comment: A potential issue with your proposed approach is induced hum.

Comment: Well The telephone is handled by a VOIP router could the interference (HUM) damage it?

Comment: I see ypu are located in Greece; I don't know what the applicable electrical code requires there. Where I live, line voltage (120-240V) and telephones/network cables (low voltage) are required to be separated by conduit or 2"/50mm physical separation, minimum. Best practice is a larger separation, particularly for parallel runs. The concern is a fault resulting in line voltage on the low voltage wiring if the two are too close to each other.

Comment: So my best bet is just run it externally and somehow cover it up with a nice wooden frame thing to look nice. (Or even place some nice LEDs as well)